# Bad search filter on LDAP when trying to get user data

Tags: php, ldap, symfony-1.4, ldap-query

I am fresh out of the box here with LDAP, so let me know if I am doing this in the completely wrong fashion.

I am working with Symfony 1.4 using the bhLDAPAuthPlugin plugin

I am verifying user login with LDAP. However, there is more data in the LDAP table that I would like to query using the username. So I am writing this search function to filter results according to the username:

```
function user_values($username) {
if (!$username) {
    die ("Username is not there man!");
}

if (!$this->_conn) {
    die ("No Connection.");
}
if (!$this->_base_dn) {
    die ("No Base.");
}
$filter="samaccountname=".$username;

$attributes_ad = array("name");
$result = ldap_search($this->_conn, $this->_base_dn, $filter, $attributes_ad) 
or die ("Error in search query");
$entries = ldap_get_entries($this->_conn, $result);
    return($entries);
}
```

I am getting the error:

**Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Bad search filter in /... Error in search query**

when i run the query.

The first three "if's" are there just to assure I was getting the correct parameters for the search. The condition fails on the actual search.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

The username variable is jtesting

I pulled the $username from the function, before it gets put in the search parameter. It is actually (jtesting). I am going to remove the parenthesis, and see if that remedies the problem.

Comment: What is the value of `$username`? Please show the actual value you are passing in...

Comment: I have added this to the question.

Comment: Hmm... well that shouldn't cause a bad filter - try changing the line where you assign filter to `$filter = '(samaccountname='.trim($username).')';`

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560874/php-ldap-add-function-to-escape-ldap-special-characters-in-dn-syntax/8561604#8561604

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use parentheses in the assertion value of a filter the parenthese must be escaped. A search filter where the assertion value is `samAccountName=(jtesting)` should be encoded as `samAccountName=\28jtesting\29`. The entire assertion value may be enclosed in parentheses which are not escaped, in which case the filter becomes `(samAccountName=\28jtesting\29)`.

#### More Information

- [LDAP: Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [String Representation of Search Filters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515#section-3)

Comment: +1 I thought this was the most likely answer. Useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560874/php-ldap-add-function-to-escape-ldap-special-characters-in-dn-syntax/8561604#8561604 :-D

Comment: It was the parenthesis. Once those were removed, the search completed successfully.