# Negated expression in LDAP Filter returns Bad Filter in PHP

Tags: php, filter, ldap

The thing is very simple:

> $results = ldap_search( $ldapconn, 'DC=testdomain,DC=com',
>   '(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=computer))' );

This works, getting 3 results.

However, negating the second expression as defined in many manuals and tutorials, returns in Bad Search Filter:

> $results = ldap_search( $ldapconn, 'DC=testdomain,DC=com',
>   '(&(objectClass=user)(!objectClass=computer))' );

Any help?

> [Wed Apr 10 16:59:05 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning: 
>   ldap_search(): Search: Bad search filter in /var/www/test2.php on line
>   29

Comment: Hmmmmmm I figured out I need to add extra parenthesis, though I don't know why and where it is explained :S since in Microsoft's documentation doesn't say so

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621450/bad-search-filter-on-ldap-when-trying-to-get-user-data

Comment: @mkaatman thanks but that isn't my problem. I figured out what it was but I can't find documentation on why it is that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because I trusted Microsoft Active Directory's Documentation on LDAP:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx

Other sites mentions the (!(expression)) like http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/dss_admin/prep_ldap.html

Comment: The syntax documented by Microsoft doesn't make sense anyway.