# issues using memberOf clause in ldap query

Tags: php, filter, ldap

I'm trying to accomplish something very similar to what this user was doing [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032351/how-to-write-ldap-query-to-test-if-user-is-member-of-a-group).

I followed the answer, but I could not get it working. Inside the Active directory, my memberOf field looks like this:

```
CN=$VPN Users,CN=Users,DC=iai,DC=pri,CN=$ITAR,CN=Users,DC=iai,DC=pri,CN=allsubscribers,CN=Users,DC=iai,DC=pri
```

My Filter that works is:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$p_username))
```

I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$p_username)(memberOf=CN=$ITAR))
```

I have tried adding the full DN which is 
    CN=Users,DC=iai,DC=pri
to my filter as well, but I get:

```
array(1) { ["count"]=> int(0) }
```

as my response.

I'm using ldap 3

This is the partial **Working** authentication code written in php:

```
  $login = ldap_bind( $url, "username@somedomain", $password ); 

  $attributes = array("displayname", "mailnickname");
  $filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$username))";

  $result = ldap_search($url, "CN=Users,DC=iai,DC=pri", $filter, $attributes);

  $entries = ldap_get_entries($url, $result);
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Code Result

From @DaveRandom

First Var dump:

```
string(49) "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=rmoser))"
array(2) {
  ["count"] => int(1)
  [0] => array(8) {
    ["displayname"] => array(2) {
      ["count"] => int(1)
      [0] => string(10) "Ryan Moser"
    }
    [0] => string(11) "displayname"
    ["memberof"] => array(4) {
      ["count"] => int(3)
      [0] => string(36) "CN=$VPN Users,CN=Users,DC=iai,DC=pri"
      [1] => string(31) "CN=$ITAR,CN=Users,DC=iai,DC=pri"
      [2] => string(40) "CN=allsubscribers,CN=Users,DC=iai,DC=pri"
    }
    [1]=> string(8) "memberof"
    ["mailnickname"] => array(2) {
      ["count"] => int(1)
      [0] => string(6) "rmoser"
    }
    [2] => string(12) "mailnickname"
    ["count"] => int(3)
    ["dn"] => string(36) "CN=Ryan Moser,CN=Users,DC=iai,DC=pri"
  }
}
bool(false)
```

Second var_dump:

```
string(70) "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=rmoser)(memberof=*CN=$ITAR*))" 
array(1) {
  ["count"] => int(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP filters look for an *exact match*.

In order to match `CN=$ITAR` anywhere in a value, you will need to surround it with the filter wildcard character `*`.

Try this filter:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$p_username)(memberOf=*CN=$ITAR*))
```

Also don't forget that `$ITAR` is a valid variable name in PHP, so if you place that filter string in double quotes (which you would need to in order for `$p_username` to be interpolated) PHP will attempt to interpolate `$ITAR` as a variable as well, find that it (probably) doesn't exist and the end result will be that it gets stripped from the string.

```
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$p_username)(memberOf=*CN=\$ITAR*))";
```

A useful link for any question concerning a dynamic filter built with PHP is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8561604/889949).

Comment: I added the wildcard flags, to make it memberOf=*CN=\$ITAR*, still no dice. The filter is valid and contains '$ITAR', however, it still returns nothing

Comment: Can you echo the filter string and see what it looks like when the variables have been substituted?

Comment: hang on a sec, your code uses `$ds` in the `ldap_bind()` call, and `$url` in the `ldap_search()` call - is that just a copy/paste typo or did you query the wrong directory?

Comment: sorry, yeah that is just a typo, its really $ds in everything, I just changed it fore ease of understanding, I'll edit that in the original question. And yeah I have been var_dumping the filter itself and it looks like this:
(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=uname)(memberOf=*CN=$ITAR*))

Comment: @Ryan Do me a favour, run [this](http://codepad.org/cy9lta3v) and add the **exact** output to the question.

Comment: @Ryan God I hate that stupid array format that `ldap_get_entries()` returns - give me a couple of minutes to decode it.

Comment: @Ryan OK that's weird, that should be matching. So you have definitely done `ldap_set_option($url, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);`? And have you set any other options? I'm guessing the problem here is that the value you are looking for is not the first value for the attribute, but I have never had this cause me a problem before. Try removing the leading `*` from the `memberOf` clause in the filter.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, it still is showing 0 results. I only have the option you mentioned set, and used your code exactly. It would be weird if the position of the value would affect this

Comment: @Ryan Well, the work around for this would be to use the code used in generating the first `var_dump()` you posted, and `strpos()` for the value you are looking for in all the attributes values. I'm now starting to wonder if this is some kind of weird character set issue, or possibly if the filter is not liking the `=` sign in the value you are searching for. Try changing the filter to `$filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$p_username)(memberOf=*CN\\3d\$ITAR*))";`

Comment: If that doesn't work try simply `$filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$p_username)(memberOf=*\$ITAR*))"‌​;`

Comment: well, I got it to work, but I had to manually go in and define it using strpos(). Still not sure why this is acting so weird, but thanks for the help!